# Error de theme.appcompat al crear un dialogo en android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, alertdialog, theme

Buenas como dice en el título, tengo el siguiente problema, tengo un alertdialog creado en una clase pero al intentar abrirlo la app me salta con el siguiente error:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.

El caso es que no entiendo el porque se está produciendo este error ya que en todas las activities y tanto en el manifest como en el styles.xml está puesto como tema por defecto Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar

Aquí dejo parte de la clase:

```
private void showGroups(){

    ListAdapter adaptet = new ArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.listview_groupsmain, R.id.groupName, g);
    listErrands.setAdapter(adaptet);
    listErrands.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position, long id) {

            AlertDialog.Builder alerDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getApplicationContext());
            alerDialogBuilder.setTitle(R.string.finisherrands);
            alerDialogBuilder.setMessage("Are you sure about that?");
            alerDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
            alerDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton(getString(R.string.yes), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finishErrands(ipServer+"finish.php", position);
                }
            });
            alerDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton(getString(R.string.no), new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
            alerDialogBuilder.create().show();

        }
    });
}
```

Aquí el manifest:

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
```

y aquí el styles.xml:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

He probado a cambiar el tema en la activity que me está dando el problema y tampoco a funcionado

Comment: Este error se debe a que estás pasando en el Builder del diálogo el context de la aplicación y la app no tiene ningún tema asociado. Para solucionarlo debes pasar el context de tu activity (this@YourActivity).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final conseguí solucionar el problema cambiando el getApplicationContext() por el nombredelaclase.this y ademas de esto cree en el archivo styles.xml un apartado para el tema del dialogo

```
<style name="MyAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <!-- Used for the buttons -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#FFC107</item>
    <!-- Used for the title and text -->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <!-- Used for the background -->
    <item name="android:background">#202732</item>
</style>troducir el código aquí
```

y el objeto del alertDialog quedaría asi

```
  AlertDialog.Builder alerDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Prueba.this, R.style.MyAlertDialogStyle);
```